# Azure Function App assigned to an App Service Plan with no App Services

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Will compute be available to an Azure Function app if it is assigned to an App Service Plan that has no App Services in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and that is in fact the way all Azure Function apps are create:

- The App Service Plan gets created first
- Then the FUnction App gets created in the App Service Plan

This applies to both Consumption and App Service Plan Function Apps

Answer (score 1):

well, the easiest way to know is to create it? that would probably take as much time as asking this question, but I don't see why it would not work.